# jquery validation submit button did not work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a code for the validation of the required fields, the validation work when there is a field without value. My problem is that, when i completely filled up all the fields the code doesn't submit my form, its just returning to the form with the values i inputted.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var rules = {
            vsi: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            date: "required",
            csname: "required",
            color: "required"
        };
        var messages = {
            vsi: {
                required: "VSI Number must be Inputted.",
                minlength: "VSI Number should be atleast 7 numbers."
            },
            date: "Date is requried",
            csname: "Customer Name is required",
             color: "Color is required"
        };


        var validator
            = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
                rules, messages);


        $("#Save").click(function ()
         {
            if (!validator.validate())

                return;
              alert("Data Saved!");

        });
    });

</script>
```

Anyone can modify my code? Thank you!

Here's my index.php

```
<?php 


    require("common.php"); 


    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 

        header("Location: login.php?attempt=1"); 

    } 


?> 
<?php
include ('connection.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.wrapper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
        var rules = {
            vsi: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            date: "required",
            csname: "required",
            color: "required"
        };
        var messages = {
            vsi: {
                required: "VSI Number must be Inputted.",
                minlength: "VSI Number should be atleast 7 numbers."
            },
            date: "Date is requried",
            csname: "Customer Name is required",
             color: "Color is required"
        };

        // 2. Initiate the validator
        var validator
            = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
                rules, messages);

        // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
        $("#Save").click(function ()
                     {
                        if (!validator.validate())
                           {
                             return;
                            }
                        $('#FormToValidate').submit();
                         alert("Data Saved!");
                          return;

                    });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>



<div id="wrapper">
<div id="innerwrapper">

        <div id="header">
          <ul id="nav">  
          <center><h3><font color="#FFFFFF">Vehicle Sales Transaction Form - UNIT VEHICLE SALES</font></h3></center> 
          </ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<br />

<div id="container">

<form action="index2.php" method="POST" >
  <a href="form_menu.php" class="small button blue">MAIN MENU</a>
  <a href="index.php" class="small button blue">EDIT</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class="small button blue">EXIT</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input name="vsisearch" type="text" style="padding-bottom:5px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="small button blue" name="Search" type="submit" id="Search" value="Search" /></form></div>
 <br/>
     <br/>
<div id="container">
    <div id="primary">
      <p>CUSTOMER NAME:</p>
        <p>VEHICLE UNIT:</p>
      <p>COLOR:</p>
        <p>CONDUCTION STICKER:</p>
        <p>MKTG. PROFESSIONAL:</p>
        <p>GROUP SALES MANAGER:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF TRANSACTION:</p>
      <p>DOWN PAYMENT:</p>
        <p>AMOUNT FINANCED:</p>
        <p>DI RATE:</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <label>PREVIOUS <br />
          </label>
        </p>
</div>
<form id="FormToValidate" action="insert.php" method="POST">
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="csname" id="csname" style="width:250px" margin-bottom="3px"/>
         </p>
        <p>
          <select name="units" style="width:254px">
            <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">AVANZA 1.3J M/T</option>
            <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">AVANZA 1.3E A/T</option>
            <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">AVANZA 1.3E M/T</option>
            <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">AVANZA 1.5G M/T</option>
            <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">AVANZA 1.5G A/T</option>
            <option value="86 2.0L A/T ">86 2.0L A/T </option>
            <option value="86 2.0L A/T (White Pearl)">86 2.0L A/T (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="86 2.0L A/T Aero">86 2.0L A/T Aero</option>
            <option value="86 2.0L A/T Aero (White Pearl)">86 2.0L A/T Aero (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="86 2.0L M/T ">86 2.0L M/T </option>
            <option value="86 2.0L M/T (White Pearl)">86 2.0L M/T (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="CAMRY 3.5Q (White Pearl)">CAMRY 3.5Q (White Pearl)4</option>
            <option value="CAMRY 3.5Q">CAMRY 3.5Q</option>
            <option value="CAMRY 2.5V ">CAMRY 2.5V </option>
            <option value="CAMRY 2.5G (White Pearl)">CAMRY 2.5G (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="CAMRY 2.5G ">CAMRY 2.5G </option>
            <option value="PRIUS C ">PRIUS C </option>
            <option value="PRIUS C (White Pearl)">PRIUS C (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="PRIUS C Full Option">PRIUS C Full Option</option>
            <option value="PRIUS C Full Option (White Pearl)">PRIUS C Full Option (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 2.0V AT (white pearl)">COROLLA 2.0V AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 2.0V AT">COROLLA 2.0V AT</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 1.6V AT (white pearl)">COROLLA 1.6V AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 1.6V AT">COROLLA 1.6V AT</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 1.6G AT">COROLLA 1.6G AT</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 1.6G MT">COROLLA 1.6G MT</option>
            <option value="COROLLA 1.6E MT">COROLLA 1.6E MT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT">FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT (white pearl)">FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT (white pearl)">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT (white pearl)">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT">FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT (white pearl)">FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT">FORTUNER 4X4V DSL AT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL AT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT">FORTUNER 4X2G DSL MT</option>
            <option value="FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT">FORTUNER 4X2G GAS AT</option>
            <option value="HIACE COMMUTER">HIACE COMMUTER</option>
            <option value="HIACE COMMUTER (WHITE)">HIACE COMMUTER (WHITE)</option>
            <option value="HIACE GL GRANDIA 1T">HIACE GL GRANDIA 1T</option>
            <option value="HIACE GL GRANDIA 2T">HIACE GL GRANDIA 2T</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER MONOTONE">HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER MONOTONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER 2-TONE">HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER 2-TONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC MONOTONE">HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC MONOTONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC 2-TONE">HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC 2-TONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE COMMUTER">HIACE COMMUTER</option>
            <option value="HIACE COMMUTER (WHITE)">HIACE COMMUTER (WHITE)</option>
            <option value="HIACE GL GRANDIA 1T">HIACE GL GRANDIA 1T</option>
            <option value="HIACE GL GRANDIA 2T">HIACE GL GRANDIA 2T</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER MONOTONE">HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER MONOTONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER 2-TONE">HIACE S GRANDIA LEATHER 2-TONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC MONOTONE">HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC MONOTONE</option>
            <option value="HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC 2-TONE">HIACE S GRANDIA FABRIC 2-TONE</option>
            <option value="HILUX 3.0L G 4X4 AT">HILUX 3.0L G 4X4 AT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 3.0L G 4X4 MT">HILUX 3.0L G 4X4 MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 2.5L G 4X2 MT">HILUX 2.5L G 4X2 MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 2.5L E 4X2 MT">HILUX 2.5L E 4X2 MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 2.5L J 4X2 MT">HILUX 2.5L J 4X2 MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX FX W/AC">HILUX FX W/AC</option>
            <option value="HILUX FX W/O AC">HILUX FX W/O AC</option>
            <option value="HILUX CAB AND CHASSIS">HILUX CAB AND CHASSIS</option>
            <option value="HILUX 4x4G AT">HILUX 4x4G AT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 4x4G MT">HILUX 4x4G MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 4x2G MT">HILUX 4x2G MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 4x2E MT">HILUX 4x2E MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX 4x2J MT">HILUX 4x2J MT</option>
            <option value="HILUX FX w/rear AC">HILUX FX w/rear AC</option>
            <option value="HILUX FX w/o rear AC">HILUX FX w/o rear AC</option>
            <option value="HILUX Cab &amp; Chassis">HILUX Cab &amp; Chassis</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5G DSL MT">INNOVA 2.5G DSL MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5G DSL AT">INNOVA 2.5G DSL AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5V DSL AT">INNOVA 2.5V DSL AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5J DSL MT">INNOVA 2.5J DSL MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5E DSL MT">INNOVA 2.5E DSL MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5E DSL AT">INNOVA 2.5E DSL AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5G DSL MT (White Pearl)">INNOVA 2.5G DSL MT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5G DSL AT (White Pearl)">INNOVA 2.5G DSL AT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.5V DSL AT (White Pearl)">INNOVA 2.5V DSL AT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0G GAS MT">INNOVA 2.0G GAS MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0G GAS AT">INNOVA 2.0G GAS AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0V GAS AT">INNOVA 2.0V GAS AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0J GAS MT">INNOVA 2.0J GAS MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0E GAS MT">INNOVA 2.0E GAS MT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0E GAS AT">INNOVA 2.0E GAS AT</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0G GAS MT (White Pearl)">INNOVA 2.0G GAS MT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="NNOVA 2.0G GAS AT (White Pearl)">NNOVA 2.0G GAS AT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="INNOVA 2.0V GAS AT (White Pearl)">INNOVA 2.0V GAS AT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO AT GAS">LC PRADO AT GAS</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO AT GAS (white pearl)">LC PRADO AT GAS (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO AT">LC PRADO AT</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO AT (white pearl)">LC PRADO AT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO MT">LC PRADO MT</option>
            <option value="LC PRADO MT (white pearl)">LC PRADO MT (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="LAND CRUISER 200">LAND CRUISER 200</option>
            <option value="LAND CRUISER 200 (White Pearl)">LAND CRUISER 200 (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="LAND CRUISER 200 Full Option">LAND CRUISER 200 Full Option</option>
            <option value="LAND CRUISER 200 Full Option (White Pearl)">LAND CRUISER 200 Full Option (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="PREVIA 2.4L FULL A/T (MC)">PREVIA 2.4L FULL A/T (MC)</option>
            <option value="PREVIA 2.4L FULL A/T (MC white pearl)">PREVIA 2.4L FULL A/T (MC white pearl)</option>
            <option value="PREVIA 2.4L STD A/T (MC)">PREVIA 2.4L STD A/T (MC)</option>
            <option value="PREVIA 2.4L STD A/T (MC white pearl)">PREVIA 2.4L STD A/T (MC white pearl)</option>
            <option value="RAV4 4X4 A/T (MC)">RAV4 4X4 A/T (MC)</option>
            <option value="RAV4 4X4 A/T (White Pearl) (MC)">RAV4 4X4 A/T (White Pearl) (MC)</option>
            <option value="RAV4 4X2 A/T (MC)">RAV4 4X2 A/T (MC)</option>
            <option value="RAV4 4X2 A/T (White Pearl) (MC)">RAV4 4X2 A/T (White Pearl) (MC)</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3E AT">VIOS 1.3E AT</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3E MT">VIOS 1.3E MT</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3J MT (IMP)">VIOS 1.3J MT (IMP)</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3J MT (OLD)">VIOS 1.3J MT (OLD)</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3 BASE MT">VIOS 1.3 BASE MT</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5 TRD A/T (white pearl)">VIOS 1.5 TRD A/T (white pearl)</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5 TRD A/T">VIOS 1.5 TRD A/T</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.3G AT (OLD)">VIOS 1.3G AT (OLD)</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5SE A/T WHITE">VIOS 1.5SE A/T WHITE</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5SE A/T">VIOS 1.5SE A/T</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5G AT">VIOS 1.5G AT</option>
            <option value="VIOS 1.5G MT">VIOS 1.5G MT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.3E AT">MC VIOS 1.3E AT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.3E MT">MC VIOS 1.3E MT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.3J MT">MC VIOS 1.3J MT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.5G MT">MC VIOS 1.5G MT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.5G AT">MC VIOS 1.5G AT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.3G AT">MC VIOS 1.3G AT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.3 BASE MT">MC VIOS 1.3 BASE MT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.5SE AT">MC VIOS 1.5SE AT</option>
            <option value="MC VIOS 1.5SE AT (White Pearl)">MC VIOS 1.5SE AT (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="YARIS 1.5 G A/T">YARIS 1.5 G A/T</option>
            <option value="YARIS 1.5 G M/T">YARIS 1.5 G M/T</option>
            <option value="TOYOTA PRIUS 1.8L Hybrid ">TOYOTA PRIUS 1.8L Hybrid </option>
            <option value="TOYOTA PRIUS 1.8L Hybrid (White Pearl)">TOYOTA PRIUS 1.8L Hybrid (White Pearl)</option>
            <option value="ALPHARD 2.4L White Pearl">ALPHARD 2.4L White Pearl</option>
            <option value="ALPHARD 2.4L">ALPHARD 2.4L</option>
            <option value="ALPHARD 3.5L White Pearl">ALPHARD 3.5L White Pearl</option>
            <option value="ALPHARD 3.5L">ALPHARD 3.5L</option>
            <option value="COASTER 30-SEAT Dsl M/T">COASTER 30-SEAT Dsl M/T</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="color" id="color" style="width:250px"/>
        </p>


      <p>
        <input type="text" name="consticker" id="consticker" style="width:250px"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <select name="mp" style="width:254px">
          <option value="AMATORIO, JESSAMYN ">AMATORIO, JESSAMYN </option>
          <option value="ANDAYA, JEDDELIA PEREZ ">ANDAYA, JEDDELIA PEREZ </option>
          <option value="BONDAD, KARYL ANN BARIAS">BONDAD, KARYL ANN BARIAS</option>
          <option value="BRIÑAS, NINA RICCI ROSE ESTIVA">BRIÑAS, NINA RICCI ROSE ESTIVA</option>
          <option value="BUSOG, MELANIE">BUSOG, MELANIE</option>
          <option value="CORNISTA, JOHN KARL CRISOSTOMO">CORNISTA, JOHN KARL CRISOSTOMO</option>
          <option value="EDAD, OLGA DESAMERO">EDAD, OLGA DESAMERO </option>
          <option value="ENDOZO, LORIE JANE SANCHEZ ">ENDOZO, LORIE JANE SANCHEZ </option>
          <option value="ESTIVA, ROYDAN BAYLON">ESTIVA, ROYDAN BAYLON </option>
          <option value="GAMARO, HONEYLET">GAMARO, HONEYLET</option>
          <option value="GONZALEZ, MADONA">GONZALEZ, MADONA</option>
          <option value="GUTIERREZ, DARA ANGELA">GUTIERREZ, DARA ANGELA </option>
          <option value="HERRERA, JAYSON">HERRERA, JAYSON </option>
          <option value="ILAGAN, FELIX DE LEON">ILAGAN, FELIX DE LEON </option>
          <option value="KATIGBAK, ARTHUR MOISES">KATIGBAK, ARTHUR MOISES</option>
          <option value="MANALILI, JASON  ">MANALILI, JASON </option>
          <option value="MARASIGAN, MICHAEL">MARASIGAN, MICHAEL </option>
          <option value="PAGCALIWAGAN, HOLLY ANN">PAGCALIWAGAN, HOLLY ANN </option>
          <option value="PANGANIBAN, TRISTAN">PANGANIBAN, TRISTAN </option>
          <option value="RAMIREZ, GERARD WEDINGCO">RAMIREZ, GERARD WEDINGCO </option>
          <option value="RAMOS, GIAN FRANCIS BRION">RAMOS, GIAN FRANCIS BRION </option>
          <option value="RAZON, NOEL">RAZON, NOEL </option>
          <option value="SALAZAR, ROBIN CARPIO">SALAZAR, ROBIN CARPIO </option>
          <option value="SOMBILLA, CELESTE MARLYNL">SOMBILLA, CELESTE MARLYN </option>
          <option value="TABABA, ROCRIS SANTHER DALE">TABABA, ROCRIS SANTHER DALE </option>
          <option value="VALENCIA, CAROL GARCIA">VALENCIA, CAROL GARCIA </option>
        </select>
      </p>
        <p>
          <select name="grm" style="width:254px">
            <option value="JOAN T. DE LUNA">JOAN T. DE LUNA</option>
            <option value="REAGER G. CARLOS">REAGER G. CARLOS</option>
            <option value="KARYL ANN B. BONDAD">KARYL ANN B. BONDAN</option>
            <option value="ALEX E. NEBRES">ALEX E. NEBRES</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p><select name="typeoftransact" style="width:254px">
<option value="CASH">CASH</option>
<option value="BANK FINANCING">BANK FINANCING</option>
<option value="BANK P.O.">BANK P.O.</option>
<option value="CORPORATE P.O.">CORPORATE P.O.</option>
<option value="GOVERNMENT P.O.">GOVERNMENT P.O.</option>
</select></p>
      <p>
        <input name="dp" type="dp" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="amount" type="amount" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="dirate" type="dirate" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="right">AMNT PAID: </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>NEXT</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

    <div id="secondary">
      <p>VSI No.:</p>
        <p>DATE:</p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 1:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 2:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 3:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 4:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 5:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>CHATTEL MORTGAGE:</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <input name="chapaid" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
    <div id="third">
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="vsi" id="vsi" style="width:180px"/>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="date" id="date" style="width:180px"/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <select name="type1" style="width:180px">
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">subd nov. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">subd dec. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">subd jan. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">subd feb. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">subd march promo</option>

  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type2" style="width:180px">
   <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">subd nov. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">subd dec. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">subd jan. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">subd feb. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">subd march promo</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type3" style="width:180px">
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">subd nov. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">subd dec. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">subd jan. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">subd feb. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">subd march promo</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type4" style="width:180px">
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">subd nov. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">subd dec. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">subd jan. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">subd feb. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">subd march promo</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type5" style="width:180px">
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3J M/T">subd nov. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E A/T">subd dec. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.3E M/T">subd jan. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G M/T">subd feb. promo</option>
    <option value="AVANZA 1.5G A/T">subd march promo</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>FREE: 
          <input name="chafree" type="text" style="width:100px" />
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="fourth">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Php: 
      <input name="type1amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type2amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type3amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type4amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type5amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>COST: 
      <input name="chacost" type="text" style="width:120px" />
    </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p align="right"><input class="small button blue" type="button" id="Save" name="Save" style="width: 80px" value="Save" /></p>


</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my action form insert.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$vsi = $_POST["vsi"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$custname = $_POST["csname"];
$unit = $_POST["units"];
$color = $_POST["color"];
$consticker = $_POST["consticker"];

$mp = $_POST["mp"];
$grm = $_POST["grm"];
$typetrans = $_POST["typeoftransact"];
$dp = $_POST["dp"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$dirate = $_POST["dirate"];
$typesub1 = $_POST["type1"];
$typesub2 = $_POST["type2"];
$typesub3 = $_POST["type3"];
$typesub4 = $_POST["type4"];
$typesub5 = $_POST["type5"];
$chacost = $_POST["chacost"];
$chapaid = $_POST["chapaid"];
$chafree = $_POST["chafree"];
$type1amount = $_POST["type1amount"];
$type2amount = $_POST["type2amount"];
$type3amount = $_POST["type3amount"];
$type4amount = $_POST["type4amount"];
$type5amount = $_POST["type5amount"];


echo('&nbsp;');
echo('&nbsp;');
echo('&nbsp;');
echo('&nbsp;');
echo('&nbsp;');

if($_POST["Save"]=="Save")
{
$query="INSERT INTO accounts (vsi,date,cname,unit,color,consticker,typetrans,downpayment,amountfinanced,dirate,mp,grm,typesub1,typesub2,typesub3,typesub4,typesub5,chapaid,chacost,chafree,type1amount,type2amount,type3amount,type4amount,type5amount)
VALUES
('".$vsi."','".$date."','".$custname."','".$unit."','".$color."','".$consticker."','".$typetrans."','".$dp."','".$amount."','".$dirate."','".$mp."','".$grm."','".$typesub1."','".$typesub2."','".$typesub3."','".$typesub4."','".$typesub5."','".$chapaid."','".$chacost."','".$chafree."','".$type1amount."','".$type2amount."','".$type3amount."','".$type4amount."','".$type5amount."');";

(mysql_query($query))

or die ("error!".mysql_error() );



}

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returning to the form?"

Comment: after i submit and the alert window (Data Saved!) was pop out, my form did not submit anything to my database and the values i inputted was remain on my form.

Comment: I have never seen such an unusual implemtation of the jQuery Validate plugin.   Can you construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: Could you please post your form code for us to see.

Comment: Can you share your markup?

Comment: ok i will post my whole code :)

Comment: i post my code because my problem now is that, its not submitting the data in database. the validation is ok, but the submission of the data to my sql server is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that validate() method makes some ajax submit or not. However, if we supposed that it submit using ajax you have to modify your last if as follows:

```
    $("#Save").click(function ()
                 {
                    if (validator.validate())
        /*
if the validate method does not submit the form on success, uncomment the following line

*/
//$('#yourFormId').submit();
                        return;
                      alert("Data Saved!");

                });
```

Comment: Well, so using your form id, you are able to use submit method. $('#formId').submit(), before the return of course.

Comment: may i ask, do you know why the data of the field are not inputted to the database? that's my problem now., thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that lacking **.submit()**

Comment: if i used .submit, my validator is not working, if i press my submit button nothing happens.

Comment: Do not quite understand the problem. Ever thought of using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form id is "FormToValidate", else none of your code will work. Also make sure you have action set to the file you are submiting to.

```
$("#Save").click(function ()
                     {
                        if (!validator.validate())
                           {
                             return;
                            }
                        $('#FormToValidate').submit();
                         alert("Data Saved!");
                          return;

                    });
```